# When it is React Hooks with Redux, must it be using selectors?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, reselect

In the old days, when React and Redux was used, some people use selectors, some people don't.

(I think it is ["reselect" npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect), but I am not sure).

However, when React has Hooks, I think we can use

```
useSelector()
useDispatch()
```

instead of all the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, `connect(...)(Component)`.  However, must we make use of `useSelector()`?  Before, we have a choice to use selector or not to use it. Is it true that after we have React Hooks and Redux, then we **have to** use selectors?

Comment: A selector function is what is passed to `useSelector`. OFC you can still use a memoized selector function from reselect.

Comment: I mean, must we use `useSelector()`?

Comment: Yes, how else would you access/"select" any state from the redux store?

Comment: aha, that's what my question is... we must use it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, the `useSelector` hook is synonymous to the `mapStateToProps` function used by the `connect` HOC. Instead of passing the `state` to the selector function in `mapStateToProps` you are passing `state` to the selector function in `useSelector`.

Comment: Do you learn these from conference, online courses, or YouTube or blogs? In the old days we learn things from textbooks... these days I don't even know how people learn these things... the one package I used for people to log in on a Ruby on Rails website was by a person by the name of technoweenie

Comment: No, mostly just read the official documentation and actually implementing something with the code.

Comment: @deeper-understanding [Here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) is an example project how I use reselect with react-redux.

Comment: @deeper-understanding the best way to learn redux are the official tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index - most other blogs are heavily outdated. Consequently, most textbooks were outdated at print - for every tech topic ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must use `useSelector`. And I think you have a bit of confusion there: If you were to use `connect` with `mapStateToProps`, you were *always* using a selector function there: `mapStateToProps` was that selector function, probably made off multiple sub-selectors that you might have been written inline or imported from somewhere.

You never "had the choice not to use a selector" though, if you wanted any value from the state. I think your concept of "what is a selector" is just a bit too strict.

You can use it two ways:

```js
// in your slice file
export const someSelector = state => state.something;
// in your component file
import someSelector from './sliceFile';
// in your component
useSelector(someSelector)
```

or just inline:

```js
useSelector(state => state.something)
```

**Both of these are selectors**, even when the second one looks a bit less like it.

One is just extracted into a function and the other one is an inline function. Both are totally okay to use and from a JS perspective, there is not a lot of difference between them.

As you mention reselect: reselect makes "memoized selectors", which is another concept on top of it. For that, you are free to use it or not use it, you're right there.

Comment: yes, I think I just use "that way", except I saw people using "reselect" at a company, and then I thought, "oh no, yet another thing..." and yet more file, yet more boilerplate. So you are saying it was all "selectors", no matter it is with, or without "reselect". It is weird to do programming these days. A guy was saying on Quora why he is not doing programming but is doing the job of a "configurator"

Comment: reselect does something on top of selectors for performance optimizations. 
Very powerful in some cases, unneccessary in others. https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Also, if you complain about boilerplate, you are probably using a very outdated style in general. Take a look at how you would write modern redux and then follow the official tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

And yes, you pretty much chose a job that consists of learning all the time. That will never stop as technology advances.

Comment: I know. If I am a fancy car salesperson or a house sales agent, I get to talk to interesting people all the time and read through magazines, and 10 years ago, it is essentially the same thing.  10 years ago, we were still using jQuery, and then Backbone, Ember, and then Angular, and then React and Flux and Redux... 5 years is already like everything has changed

Comment: so we are moving towards Redux Toolkit now?  No problem, "just" another 27 pages to read (again)

Comment: Yes, it is the official recommendation for one and a half years now.